# I have to check if data exists or not in a database in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two methods, one to insert, update and delete and a second is checking whether data already exists in my database or not. The main purpose of all code is that I don't want to insert duplicate data into the database.

```
public class DAL : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection connection;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataTable dt;

    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    public int numofrows;

    //Connection Method
    public void Connection()
    {
        connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        connection.Open();
    }

    //This Method will Insert,Update and Delete in Database
    public void InsertUpdateDelete(string query)
    {
        ////connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=IM-82B70624D72D;Initial Catalog=AppointmentScheduler;User ID=sa;Password=za3452432760za");
        //connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        //connection.Open();
        this.Connection();
        cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        numofrows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
    }

    //This Method will read data From Database
    public DataTable ReadData(string Query)
    {
        this.Connection();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(Query, connection);
        dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Data already Exist");
        }

        return dt;
    }
}
```

I have to use both above code in `index.aspx`. How can I use both above code in `index.aspx`?

I tried to use but that is not working.

`index.aspx` code:

```
    protected void btnSaveDays_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.query = "SELECT DaysName FROM Dayss WHERE Day_Id='" + DropDownListDays.SelectedValue + "'";
        dal.ReadData(this.query);

        this.query = "INSERT INTO Dayss VALUES ('" + DropDownListDays.SelectedItem.Text + "')";
        dal.InsertUpdateDelete(this.query);
        Response.Write("Day Inserted Successfully");
    }
```

But this code is not working and generating error

> Conversion failed

Comment: Is your `Day_Id` column is character type? Smells like it is not. Your `Dayss` table has just one column by the way? If not, use your column name in your `INSERT` statement.

Comment: not Day_Id is int, and Dayss have two columns. One is id and second is name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> not Day_Id is int, and Dayss have two columns. One is id and second is
>   name

Then there is no point to use single quotes with `int` typed column value. Single quotes is for character column values.

```
this.query = "SELECT DaysName FROM Dayss WHERE Day_Id = " + DropDownListDays.SelectedValue ;
```

And if you want to insert just one column, you need specify your column name in your `Dayss` table like;

```
this.query = "INSERT INTO Dayss (YourColumnName) VALUES ('" + DropDownListDays.SelectedItem.Text + "')";
```

Take a look [`INSERT (Transact-SQL)`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx)